# How to properly style the Select2 outline on :focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) to style my `<select>` boxes, but I can't seem to style the forced outline which Chrome applies to the style:

Problem:
[image]

I've tried several lines of (very unprofessionally, `!important`) CSS code, but so far I haven't come up with the solution, this is what i'm at right now:

CSS:

```
.select2 > *:focus, .select2:focus .select2 > *, .select2 {
    outline-width: 0px !important;
}
```

For the sake of excluding potential problems, i'm definitely including this CSS file, *after* my regular select2.css

Also, a fiddle would be problematic, but I could provide one if really necessary

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
  <style>
    .select2-container *:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
  </style>
```

Here is [a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gcuYRqjV8MY1MMrH73b0?p=preview).

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks Dave, this is a 100% more cleaner than my inital solution: `select + span.select2:focus, select + span.select2 *:focus {
 outline-color: #7d3c8c;
 outline-width: 1px;
}`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
&.select2-container--focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because neither select2 or chrome use the `outline` property. Here is the actual definition of `select:focus` pseudo element in select2 (+bootstrap):

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

Try changing `border` and `box-shadow` instead :

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: unset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: It in some way explained to me why this problem appeared, but i'm not implementing forms from bootstrap, so this solution will not work for me. But thank you for the time and energy!

Answer (score 0):

It using box shadow, not outline, look at the inspector:

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

so you need to reset it

Comment: I'm a 100% sure it's not using `box-shadow` and frankly, that didn't work.

Comment: Update: this is mainly because i'm not using bootstrap for this form

Comment: i have followed your lik to select2, so you are using older version i think

Comment: Hmmm, `package.json` in my `node_modules` tells me i'm on: `"version": "4.0.3",`